# How to read Build-Action: Resource items

Tags: c#, wpf, resources, embedded-resource

How do you read a resource that has build action **Resource** instead of build-action **Embedded Resource**. The layout of **Resource** is waay better, but I want to know how to do it without using the `Application` (WPF) object.

Comment: have you tried `ResourceManager`?

Answer (score 2):

I have done this for gathering images from the resources where the build action is `Resource` from an external application. However we have to have a reference to `System.Windows.Resources` and use the `Application.GetResourceStream()`

Basically we use the following method.

```
    private static Stream GetResourceStream(string resourcePath)
    {
        try
        {

            string s = System.IO.Packaging.PackUriHelper.UriSchemePack;
            var uri = new Uri(resourcePath);
            StreamResourceInfo sri = System.Windows.Application.GetResourceStream(uri);
            return sri.Stream;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Now this returns a stream which can then by converted to a byte[] array or used to build other object types.

This could be called like.

```
            //set variables
            string myAssembly = "Test.Assembly";
            string resourceItem = "resources/myimage.png";

            //get the stream
            using (var bSteam = GetResourceStream(string.Format("pack://application:,,,/{0};component//{1}", myAssembly, resourceItem)))
            {
                //covert the stream to a memory stream and return the byte array
                using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    bSteam.CopyTo(ms);
                    return ms.ToArray();
                }
            }
```

Like I said it does use the Application.GetResourceStream(). If you want to avoid using this method this answer may not be suitable.

Cheers,

Comment: Yeah. I mean I know how to read resources from an assembly, but WPF seems to do a good job at structuring the names (better than an embedded resource). I would like to do this, but in a *non* WPF application - so I can't really use an `Application` object.